# usage of relative pronoun *which*

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, commas

I am having a problem in using the relative pronoun *which* inappropriately.
Hence I would like to confirm that the below sentence is a right usage of it.

> Animals & birds are butchered for food by humans, which a few folks
>   support it by stating that the ecological balance rests entirely upon one
>   depending on the other for food

Can this sentence be constructed in any other form to make it clear.

Secondly, can I use a comma before words such as *who* , *which*, *where*, *while*
in a sentence for sentence clarity?

For example, in the above example I used as "food by humans, which few folks". Is this comma acceptable?

Comment: I have edited your question and, in particular, your example sentence so the only error to be discussed is the one you ask about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Animals and birds are butchered for food by humans, **which** a few folks support **it** by stating that the ecological balance is based upon one depending on the other for food.

In a relative clause, the relative pronoun **replaces*** one constituent of a full sentence and then 'moves' to the head. The correct phrasing of your relative clause is constructed like this:

```
      A few folks support   it    by stating &c ...
                             ↓
      A few folks support [which] by stating &c ...
    ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ↵
   ↓
which a few folks support         by stating &c ...
```

Note the ‘gap’ between *support* and *by*. (Of course you take out all the extra white space when you write it.) Your mistake is that you have left in place the constituent—*it*—which is supposed to be replaced by *which*, so the verb now has two direct objects, *which* and *it*.

Your comma is proper. It makes clear that *which* does not refer to *humans* but to the entire sentence which precedes it:

```
      A few folks support [(that) animals and birds are butchered for food by humans].
                                                     ↓
      A few folks support                            it  
                                                     ↓
      A few folks support                         [which].
```